# How to Add Multiple Gradle Projects into same IntelliJ Instance

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-12

I get the below exception when I try to import my other projects as a module into same IntelliJ instance. I use `IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4`

```
Could not fetch model of type 'BasicIdeaProject' using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\gradle-1.6'.
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.


Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Reveal Log)
```

I feel I need to change the JVM parameters somewhere but not sure the exact place.

Answer (score 0):

I added below line to the `gradle.properties` file located in  `C:\Users\username\.gradle`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms128m -Xmx256m
```

Above doesn't give me the error and added the project like a charm. But still it remove the existing project and add the new project. So still one project per instance. :(